# EXTJS Chart not displaying all markers names on the x-Axis

Tags: extjs, charts, extjs4, axis, label

I'm developing an application with Ext JS 4.1.3.  The application processes data and shows a chart on basis of the data.

The problem is:
In the case, where there are more than 80-90 entries on the chart (on x-Axis), some marker names are omitted.  So, instead of the markers names it shows partially empty positions.  Although there is still a lot of space.

**Here is a screenshot:**

[image]

And the questions are:

- I made font of the markers smaller already. Maybe there is a way to reduce the padding between the marks?
- How can I force the ExtJs chart to show all entries?  Can I change the setting of the chart (or x-Axis) to display all the markers names (regardless of the number of the entries) ?
- Are there other solutions to this problem?

Thanks!

**UPD1.**  This is somehow related to css class " x-hide-visibility" and hideMode.

- How can I disable the hideMode of labels?

**UPD2.**  I have found the following solution. But it made the chart slow (not critical, but..).  Maybe someone knows other solution?  There must be a way to switch off the  option ('hideMode') in advance.

```
for (var i = 0; i< chart.axes.items[0].labelGroup.items.length; i++){
    chart.axes.items[0].labelGroup.items[i].el.removeCls(' x-hide-visibility');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved the hidden labels issue by adding this line of css to a stylesheet.

svg text.x-hide-visibility {visibility: inherit!important;}

It would be nice if there was some configuration option on the series or axes to control this behavior. Hope it works for you!

Comment: I thank you for the answer. You've got a similar solution. There is another variant from Sencha Forum: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?259151-Column-Chart-not-displaying-all-markers-names-on-the-Category-Axis&p=949823&viewfull=1#post949823

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.

Please just add the following line:

chrChart1.ChartAreas(0).AxisX.Interval = 1

Comment: What does it do? How does it help?